# Layer of one element stacking over another during animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Filling a card from bottom to top with the specified color (this works) on hover.
2. Still on hovering the card, I want to display a rocket launch animation.

I have the problem that the `.rocket::before` element does not want to be displayed behind the `.rocket` element.

I have the following code:

```css
.main-nav-card {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent 50%,
    #1c7ed6 50%
  );
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 70rem;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding: 4.8rem 9.6rem;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-large);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-nav-card:hover {
  animation-name: fillCard;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fillCard {
  from {
    background-position: top;
  }

  to {
    background-position: bottom;
  }
}

.rocket {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  /* z-index: 20; */
}

.rocket::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -15px;

  height: 20px;
  width: 55px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  background-color: #f03e3e;

  z-index: -1;
}

.rocket::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: -4px;

  height: 4px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  background-color: #f03e3e;
  z-index: -1;
}

.main-nav-card:hover .rocket {
  display: block;
  animation-name: flyRocket;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes flyRocket {
  from {
    transform: translateY(1000%);
    /* z-index: 9999; */
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    /* z-index: 9999; */
  }
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
}

.window {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
  left: 7.5px;
  /* transform: translateX(25%); */
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav-card">
  <p class="card-title">Introduction</p>

  <div class="rocket">
    <div class="window"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example has been given.

Comment: It would be easier to help if an example were embedded into your question via SO's built-in snippets. Regardless, your code seems incomplete because when I recreate the provided code on my machine, I only see an empty page with the word "Introduction".

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Now it should work

Comment: Edited my answer because apparently `preserve-3d` isn't reliable on iOS Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this issue is due to the [CSS "transform" property creating a new stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context#:%7E:text=Element%20with%20any,transform) on the rocket, which prevents child elements and pseudo elements from appearing behind the stacking context root (`.rocket`). As a result, the fix is to put your `.rocket` element in some wrapper element and apply the transform on the wrapper instead. That way, the stacking context is created on the wrapper rather than on the rocket directly, enabling any child and pseudo elements to appear behind it once again.

However, there is a better way to do this, using the `translateZ()` and `preserve-3d`. Specifically, instead of managing z-indexes on your pseudo elements, use `transform: translateZ(-1px);` to put them behind the parent element. Then, all you have to do to make it work is apply `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the `.rocket` selector. This works in <strike>all</strike> most modern browsers. Here is the full code:

```css
.main-nav-card {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, #1c7ed6 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 70rem;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding: 4.8rem 9.6rem;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-large);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-nav-card:hover {
  animation-name: fillCard;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fillCard {
  from {
    background-position: top;
  }
  to {
    background-position: bottom;
  }
}

.rocket {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.rocket::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 55px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  background-color: #f03e3e;
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}

.rocket::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  background-color: #f03e3e;
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}

.main-nav-card:hover .rocket {
  display: block;
  animation-name: flyRocket;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes flyRocket {
  from {
    transform: translateY(1000%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
}

.window {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
  left: 7.5px;
  /* transform: translateX(25%); */
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav-card">
  <p class="card-title">Introduction</p>

  <div class="rocket">
    <div class="window"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: Apparently this doesn't work for iOS Safari because `perserve-3d` is [somewhat broken](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71624) there. So if you really want to support all browsers, you should use the wrapper element technique.